# Issues with Azure IOT Edge & Jetson Nano - DeepStream Module

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, nvidia-jetson-nano, nvidia-deepstream

I'm trying to install the Nvidia DeepStream SDK module on my Jetson Nano running JetPack 4.6.1 with Azure IOT Edge.

Following this example, but it is based on DeepStream 5.1, and since I have JetPack 4.6.1 I have DeepStream SDK 6.0.1
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/NVIDIA-Deepstream-Azure-IoT-Edge-on-a-NVIDIA-Jetson-Nano

I'm getting this error when deploying the DeepStream SDK 5.1 module from the marketplace.

```
2022-05-21 16:52:36.053 +00:00 [ERR] - Edge agent plan execution failed.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error calling start module NVIDIADeepStreamSDK: Could not start module NVIDIADeepStreamSDK
    caused by: Could not start module NVIDIADeepStreamSDK
    caused by: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: error adding seccomp filter rule for syscall clone3: permission denied: unknown)
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.EdgeletCommunicationException- Message:Error calling start module NVIDIADeepStreamSDK: Could not start module NVIDIADeepStreamSDK
    caused by: Could not start module NVIDIADeepStreamSDK
    caused by: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: error adding seccomp filter rule for syscall clone3: permission denied: unknown, StatusCode:500, at:   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.Version_2021_12_07.ModuleManagementHttpClient.HandleException(Exception exception, String operation) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/edge-agent/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet/version_2021_12_07/ModuleManagementHttpClient.cs:line 231
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.Versioning.ModuleManagementHttpClientVersioned.Execute[T](Func`1 func, String operation) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/edge-agent/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet/versioning/ModuleManagementHttpClientVersioned.cs:line 155
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.Version_2021_12_07.ModuleManagementHttpClient.StartModuleAsync(String name) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/edge-agent/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet/version_2021_12_07/ModuleManagementHttpClient.cs:line 179
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.ModuleManagementHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<<Throttle>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/edge-agent/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet/ModuleManagementHttpClient.cs:line 140
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Which DeepStream SDK container should I use instead on my Jetson Nano?